# Where did the link to the help go?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, help-center, top-bar

The top bar has changed and I can't see the link to help any more.

Where do I find the help pages now? Are they gone?

(Everyone should be seeing the change now.)

Comment: What is happening? I am still seing the old layout, are you seeing the new?

Comment: @kjetil yes, at the time I posted I didn't realize we mods were actually the only ones seeing it, but apparently that's the situation -- I suppose we're the guinea pigs but I wish that had been made clearer to us. So this will be a much more useful question once it clicks in site-wide. I expect that will happen very soon

Comment: I wonder if we should put the `[status-completed]` tag on this thread now?

Comment: It seems we shouldn't use `status` tags on `support` questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note: the link to help can now be found under the SE 'hamburger' with chat.**

---

In some ways, I think the new top bar is better than the old one.  Not having a convenient link to the help or tour pages, etc., was a mistake, though, in my opinion.  You can still find links to those in the bottom left corner of every page under "CROSS VALIDATED".

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I always looked for the links at the bottom of the screen... But I liked the previous bar better. Icons are pretty cluttered in the new one.

Answer (score 7):

In case you missed it, the link to the help is back (next to other buttons on top-right menu).

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a new development. A good one.

Answer (score 4):

Users with low reputation should still see a help link in the top bar, but users with (I think) more than some particular amount of reputation will see other tools in the same position.

The help pages are still there. Indeed there's a link to them at the *bottom* of each page, in the leftmost list of links

Comment: I can't see the new top bar here, yet; but on Stack Overflow. Isn't the help link embedded in the upper rightest icon (the one with horizontal parallel bars)?

Comment: This menu? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwYWC.png

Comment: [Yeap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYBkH.png), :(